# Can $0$ be an element of a harmonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

The definition of a harmonic series is that for any $H_{k-1},H_k,H_{k+1} \in \{H_1,H_2, ... H_n\}$, $$\frac{2}{H_k} = \frac{1}{H_{k-1}} + \frac{1}{H_{k+1}}$$

If any $H_k$ is zero, then $\frac 1 {H_k}$ is not defined, hence **zero cannot be an element of a harmonic progression**.

Does this proof hold good? If not, give an example of a harmonic series with zero as one of it's elements.

Comment: An harmonic progression is not an harmonic *series*.

Comment: If we Interpret "harmonic series" as harmonic number $H(z)$, then we have the recursion $H(z) = H(z-1) +\frac{1}{z}$. From $H(1)=1$ you can easily deduce that $H(0)=0$. You can also show that $H(z)=0$ has infinitely many solutions for $z<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is debatable.

We can easily state

$$H_{k-1}\ne0\land H_{k+1}\ne0\implies H_{k}\ne0$$

but it could turn out that all $H$ are zero and the "definition" can never be used. A zero sequence cannot be disproven harmonic.